# Mapping keys optimization in Solidity

Tags: mapping, solidity-0.7.x

I've looked through all answers here but still have the question for the latest version of Solidity.
Perhaps, there exist new libraries
Is it possible to optimize this

```
mapping(address => uint) balances;
mapping(address => bool) staked;
```

Into just one mapping but with the function to check if an address ever staked at this moment?
Using Solidity version 0.7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you combine this data into one mapping of structs? Example:

```
struct sampleStruct {
    uint balance;
    bool staked;
}

mapping(address => sampleStruct) sampleStructs;
```

Then your method that check if an address ever staked will look like this:

```
function checkIfStaked(address _address) public view returns(bool) {
    if (sampleStructs[_address].staked) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or simply `return sampleStructs[_address].staked;`.

Comment: This works also since ```staked``` is a boolean.

Comment: @MiroslavNedelchev If there's no such an address in the mapping yet, will it return 0 or null as long as null doesn't exist in Solidity?

Comment: @DmitryDyachkov it will return false for not existing addresses in the mapping. Is this what you need?